# Using GitHub Checks Annotations from Azure Pipelines

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, github-api, github-check-run

**Summary**

I want to add annotations to GitHub CI runs from inside Azure Pipelines. I want to add these annotations to the CI Check Run that is performing the build. I do not know how to get at the GitHub Check Run identifier from inside Azure, and I do not know of any Azure-specific API for adding annotations to the job results.

**Background Details**

I would like to add [Checks Annotations](https://developer.github.com/v3/checks/runs/#annotations-object-1) to [GitHub Pull Requests using Azure DevOps CI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops-project/azure-devops-project-github).

Specifically, I want to pipe build failures from Clang/GCC or MSVC to annotations, as well as pipe requested changes from tools like clang-tidy or clang-format.

Writing a script that parses outputs from these tools and makes requests with [GitHub Octokit](https://developer.github.com/v3/libraries/) is easy enough, if that is required, so I'm not worried about the mechanism of annotations.

I'm aware of the [logging commands](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/blob/master/docs/authoring/commands.md) supported. However, even setting errors like:

```
##vso[task.logissue type=error;sourcepath=source/test.cpp;linenumber=7;columnnumber=20]Error
```

Does not set GitHub Annotations. Even if it did, I don't know how I could fit a multi-line comment (like a diff, or even most compiler errors for that matter) into a log-based structure like that.

**The Problem**

I would like to add these annotations to the existing Check Run that is running the script, but this requires that I be able to get the Check Run identifier.

Either I need to get at this id for my own purposes (and I don't know how!) or I need access to an API of some kind from inside Azure Pipelines that adds annotations (but I'm not aware of any).